# installing the ELRepo repository on centos 8 ends with "glibc = 2.17 is needed" error

Tags: centos8, glibc

i'm trying to upgrade centos 8.2 kernel from 4.x to 5.x to resolve the network latency issue caused by network interface driver (TCP packet incompatibilty).

so i tried:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
```

and then:

```
rpm -Uvh https://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
```

this is the response:

```
Retrieving https://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm | error: Failed dependencies:  glibc = 2.17 is needed by elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch
```

as current glibc is 2.28.x so i tried:

```
yum downgrade glibc\*
```

and i got this:

```
Package glibc of lowest version already installed, cannot downgrade it.
```

as far as i know changing glibc version can cause issues for other installed packages.
so what should i do ?

Comment: You're trying to add an EL7 repo to EL8.  Add the correct repo for the EL version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `elrepo-release` RPM for CentOS 8, not the one for CentOS 7.

Download and install the correct package.